# How to get time duration since midnight

Tags: rust

How to get time duration since midnight (in secsonds, milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds) in Rust? I am only aware of getting the duration since `UNIX_EPOCH`

```
SystemTime::now().duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).expect("Time went backwards");
```

Comment: You could try [chrono::naive::NaiveTime::num_seconds_from_midnight](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveTime.html#method.num_seconds_from_midnight).

Comment: Do you wish to know the duration since midnight UTC, or midnight in a specific timezone?

Comment: better to know both options

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want the time of day in UTC, your local time zone, or some other specific zone.

In general, you can use the `time` crate to get the time of day with [`OffsetDateTime::time()`](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.OffsetDateTime.html#method.time). `OffsetDateTime` values are created with a specific time zone; the type provides [`now_utc()`](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.OffsetDateTime.html#method.now_utc) and [`now_local()`](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.OffsetDateTime.html#method.now_local) for UTC and local time, respectively. If you need a different time zone, you can call [`to_offset()`](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.OffsetDateTime.html#method.to_offset) to convert to it.